# Copy a column with mixed currencies using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet tab that needs to be copied to another sheet. In most columns I can set the formatting to the proper currency formatting, so when copying the column, the format is kept and the data is copied correctly.

In one of the columns I have some of the cells in one currency, and some other cells in another currency, therefore I cannot apply a currency formatting to this column, and this column has an automatic formatting.

When copying this column, the numbers are copied as values without formatting and displayed as plain numbers.

I am copying the values with the CopyValuesToRange method.

Is there a way to copy the text as is - with the currency sign? Or maybe apply a conditional currency formatting for each cell based on the cell's text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `copyValuesToRange` does what its name suggests: copies *values* to range.  You want to copy both the values **and** formatting. For this, use the [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("A1:A5").copyTo(sheet.getRange("B1:B5"), {formatOnly: true});
sheet.getRange("A1:A5").copyTo(sheet.getRange("B1:B5"), {contentsOnly: true});
```

The first step, `formatOnly: true`,  copies over the formatting. The second copies values only (static values, not the formulas that they came from).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the CopyTo method copies the formulas of the cell as well, which I don't want because the formulas are referring to other sheets in this spreadsheet, and I am copying this sheet to another spreadsheet, and that causes errors.
Using the {contentsOnly:true} options acts just like the CopyValuesToRange method

Comment: Doing it separately with format and contents seems to work: see the updated answer.